# UIBarButtonItems not showing up after creating UIToolbar programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I'm running across this issue which I can't seem to find the answer to online. Basically what I'm trying to do is programmatically create a `UIToolbar` with some `UIBarButtonItems`.

What I've done (as detailed below) is create the `UIToolbar` and then set the items of the `UIToolbar` to an array holding all the `UIBarButtonItems` I want.

Unfortunately, though the `UIToolbar` shows up, the `UIBarButtonItems` have yet to show themselves

Any suggestions or explanations as to why this is happening is much appreciated!

```
class DrawViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //create bar buttons
        let deleteBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "greyDelete"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "deleteView:")
        let eraseBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "greyErase"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "erase:")
        let resizeBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "greyResize"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "resize:")
        let viewBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "greyView"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "view:")
        let colorBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "greyColor"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "color:")
        let drawBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "greyDraw"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "draw:")
        let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)

        //set up toolbar
        let toolbarItems = [deleteBarButton, flexibleSpace, eraseBarButton, 
                            flexibleSpace, resizeBarButton, flexibleSpace, 
                            viewBarButton, flexibleSpace, colorBarButton, 
                            flexibleSpace, drawBarButton]
        let toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, view.bounds.height*0.93, view.bounds.width, view.bounds.height*0.7))
        toolbar.barTintColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "blueToolbar")!)
        toolbar.setItems(toolbarItems, animated: true)
        self.view.addSubview(toolbar)
    }
```

[As you can see only the toolbar show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgv5q.png)

[And the image names (of the images used to create the UIBarButtons) are the same names as those in the Assets catalog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlxHI.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would imagine the problem is the curious way you're creating the `UIToolbar`. This line here seems deeply suspect:

```
let toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, view.bounds.height*0.93, view.bounds.width, view.bounds.height*0.7))
```

Why make it 0.7 times the height of your view?

To fix this problem, create the toolbar either without the frame constructor or with `CGRectZero` for its frame. Then use `sizeToFit()` to make it the appropriate size.

A simpler alternative, if possible, is to use a `UINavigationController` and tell it to show its own toolbar. You can then fill that by setting your view controller's `toolbarItems` property to your array, and it will all work without you having to create, position or manage a `UIToolbar` at all.

Comment: Wow now I can see all my buttons! Thank-you! But now the toolbar shows up at the top of the screen instead of the bottom. Would you know how I could place the toolbar at the bottom?

Comment: Nevermind I've figured it out! But thank-you for your help! You saved me so much time!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it worked. Could you mark my answer as correct so that others can benefit too? Thank you!